# PHP format thousand number with leading dot before doing math subtraction?

Tags: php, math, integer

I am trying tu do substraction with two numbers in thousand which are formatted like below, but I cannot figure out using `number_format()` function to get the `thousand` display without the leading `"dot"` as a separator and do the math as follows.

Getting result 0,032 instad of just 32

```
<?php
$a = "1.545"; // how to format this to 1545? (here could be 0, 1, 6, 10, 54, 389, 600, 1600, 5000)
$b = "1.513";  // how to format this to 1545? (here could be 0, 1, 6, 10, 54, 389, 600, 1600, 5000)
$c = $a- $b; // subtraction
echo $c; // result 0,032 instad of just 32
?>
```

How can I format 1.545 to 1545 and then do the substraction?

Comment: Should I multiply the number with 100? - but will get the wrong number if I will have 654, or 35, or 7 ...

Comment: Or, this is string, so I can do str_replace()?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working! Result 32

```
<?php
$a = "1.545";
$b = "1.513";
$c = intval(str_replace('.','',$a))-intval(str_replace('.','',$b));
echo $c;
?>
```